# Can we use an array into another array in C?

Tags: c

Can we use an array as an argument of another array?

I tried it in `C` programming language in Visual studio 2013 and It doesn't work!

Comment: What went wrong in what you tried will forever remain a mystery unless you *post your code* in your question. Arrays of arrays are a supported language feature (if that was really what your post is about; that remains unclear as well).

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm you should read some book of C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an array, as of c99, this is **not** an valid operation

```
int main(void)
{
  int vec[3]={1,2,3};
  int sel[2]={1,2};
  vec[sel];  // Invalid, will cause compilation to fail
  return 0;
}
```

In order to select all of the variables you would have to loop through the array

```
int main(void)
{
  int vec[3]={1,2,3};
  int sel[2]={1,2};
  int i;
  int indv;
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
     indv=vec[sel[i]];
     ## dosomething to indv
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really get no error or warning for `vec[sel]`? However, at least this is meaningless code producing undefined behavior.

Comment: You are correct, it does fail to compile. I made a note of it above, saying that it is not a valid operation, but will add a comment to clarify.

Comment: No, you made a note, that it is not an *in*valid operation.